# eucalyptus started but appear error

Tags: linux, cloud, eucalyptus

I installed eucalyptus, but when i start eucalyptus , it's appear mistake. I check file eucanetd.log, it show following:

```
 2014-12-11 11:40:01 ERROR | command failed: exitcode='256' command='//usr/lib/eucalyptus/euca_rootwrap /usr/sbin/dhcpd -cf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.conf -lf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.leases -pf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.pid -tf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.trace'
2014-12-11 11:40:01 ERROR | unable to (re)configure local dhcpd server: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:01 ERROR | could not complete update of private IPs: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:01  INFO | new networking state (VM public network addresses): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:01  INFO | new networking state (VM network isolation): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:02  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updating system
2014-12-11 11:40:02  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:02  INFO | new networking state (VM public/private network addresses, VM network isolation): updating system
2014-12-11 11:40:02 ERROR | command failed: exitcode='256' command='//usr/lib/eucalyptus/euca_rootwrap /usr/sbin/dhcpd -cf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.conf -lf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.leases -pf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.pid -tf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.trace'
2014-12-11 11:40:02 ERROR | unable to (re)configure local dhcpd server: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:02 ERROR | could not complete update of private IPs: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:02  INFO | new networking state (VM public network addresses): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:02  INFO | new networking state (VM network isolation): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:03  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updating system
2014-12-11 11:40:03  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:03  INFO | new networking state (VM public/private network addresses, VM network isolation): updating system
2014-12-11 11:40:03 ERROR | command failed: exitcode='256' command='//usr/lib/eucalyptus/euca_rootwrap /usr/sbin/dhcpd -cf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.conf -lf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.leases -pf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.pid -tf //var/run/eucalyptus/net/euca-dhcp.trace'
2014-12-11 11:40:03 ERROR | unable to (re)configure local dhcpd server: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:03 ERROR | could not complete update of private IPs: check above log errors for details
2014-12-11 11:40:04  INFO | new networking state (VM public network addresses): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:04  INFO | new networking state (VM network isolation): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:05  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updating system
2014-12-11 11:40:05  INFO | new networking state (VM security groups): updated successfully
2014-12-11 11:40:05  INFO | new networking state (VM public/private network addresses, VM network isolation): updating system
```

Any help?

Cheers,

Nghiep

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have `/usr/sbin/dhcpd` on the system. and this is file configure of eucalyptus.

```
EUCALYPTUS="/"
LOGLEVEL="INFO"
EUCA_USER="eucalyptus"
CLOUD_OPTS=""
NC_PORT="8775"
CC_PORT="8774"
SCHEDPOLICY="ROUNDROBIN"
NODES="10.10.2.11"
NC_SERVICE="axis2/services/EucalyptusNC"
HYPERVISOR="kvm"
MAX_CORES="0"
INSTANCE_PATH="/var/lib/eucalyptus/instances"
USE_VIRTIO_ROOT="1"
USE_VIRTIO_DISK="1"
USE_VIRTIO_NET="1"
VNET_MODE="EDGE"
VNET_PRIVINTERFACE="br0"
VNET_PUBINTERFACE="br0"
VNET_BRIDGE="br0"
VNET_DHCPDAEMON="/usr/sbin/dhcpd"
METADATA_USE_VM_PRIVATE="N"
DISABLE_TUNNELING="Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `/usr/sbin/dhcpd`on the system? If not, you either need to point Eucalyptus to the right location of your DHCP daemon using `VNET_DHCPDAEMON` parameter in the `/etc/eucalyptus/eucalyptus.conf` file or you need to install a DHCP daemon and ensure that the parameter above is pointing to it.

Comment: Yes, I have /usr/sbin/dhcpd on the system. But it's not start

Answer (score 0):

There may be a [port conflict with dnsmasq](https://eucalyptus.atlassian.net/browse/EUCA-10166) preventing dhcpd from starting. Check if the "default" network is active on the node controller:

```
# virsh net-list
```

if it is then you can use:

```
# virsh net-destroy default
```

to destroy the default network and stop the associated dnsmasq process allowing dhcpd to run.